# How set minimum and maximum validation for Integer in odoo8?

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

```
_columns = {
    'product_id': fields.many2one('ims.product', 'Product', required=True),
    'qty' : fields.integer('Qty', required=True),
    'cost': fields.float('Product Cost',digits=(12,2), required=True),
    'total_cost': fields.float('Total Cost', digits=(12,2), required=True)
}
```

The `qty` field must accept minimum 10 and maximum 100. How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

define a function _check_qty, that returns a true when qty between min and max

```
def _check_qty(self,cr,uid,ids):
    for product in self.browse(cr, uid, ids):
        min, max = 0,100
        min = product.min
        max = product.max
        if not min <product.qty < max: return False 
    return True
_constraints = [(_check_qty, 'Please inter other qty !', ['qty'])]
```

Comment: `_constraints Deprecated since version 8.0: use constrains()` How to use constrains()?

Comment: The sntaxe of constraint is  : `(constraint_function, message, fields)`  see python file account.py in account module , line 139-147

Comment: Nice... min and max is dynamic, I want to fetch from database, how i can do that?

Comment: You mean, find min and max in the database

Comment: Thanks... is it possible to remove the default display in odoo warning alert. In bottom its displaying `Error details:
can't adapt type 'ims.product'`

Comment: So, we need to intialize min, and max

Comment: Inside `for product in self.browse(cr, uid, ids):` if i user product.product_id, its coming `ims.product(26,)`. But product_id is 26 only. What i have to do here?

Comment: You forget adding `.id` , so the correct id is : `product.product_id.id`

Comment: I have to get the product_id from the form like qty. Now if I `print print(product.product_id)` output is `ims.product(26,)`. But i need only `26`. How i have to print it?

Comment: `print product.product_id.id`